# How do I install webpack version 4.19.1?

Tags: npm, webpack

My system already has webpack version `4.27.5`, but I need to uninstall this version and then use an older version `4.19.1`, instead. I'm using Ubuntu.

I've run the command:

```
npm uninstall <web package>
```

but my issue was not resolved.

Comment: Hello & welcome to StackOverflow ! Please reformat your issue, using code tags, to make it easier to read :)

Comment: Edited to clarify "webpack" was the subject of the question. I added `npm` and `webpack` as tags and removed the Linux tag, as this seems to pertain more to npm and JavaScript rather than Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to create a `.npmrc` file and add it

```
save-exact=true
```

This will prevent you from get packages like "^4.19.1", which AFAIK this means, get any package above 4.19.1

and then just install the needed package using the following command

```
npm install webpack@4.19.1 --save-dev
```